# Is there a way to find the two generator polynomials of a JPL sequence?

Tags: decryption, lfsr

I am decoding a binary sequence that was detected as an unpractically long LFSR by the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm. First of all, the generated sequence is far longer than it needs to be and since it needs to be decoded in real-time in the application, the LFSR is so long that the latency would be unpractically high. It doesn't make sense really.

So I am suspecting this to be a JPL sequence, which as far as I understand is comprised of two LFSRs that are relatively prime to each other and can generate much longer sequences. Literature says that it was developed to decrease synchronization time of long signals. Please correct me if I am wrong!

If so, is there a way to find the two single LFSRs of the JPL sequence?

If not, what other type of sequence could this be?

Here is a sample of the sequence:

```
0000011100111111111100000111110001100000111111111100011111110000011111111001111100000111001111111111111000000011111000111111111100111111110011111111001110000011111111110011100111111110011111000110001100000111110000011111000110001111111000001110011100111
```

Comment: can you be more concrete about the length you say is impractical, and whatever else you have, e.g., how long is the sequence sample? and cite the literature you are quoting.

Comment: Sure, the LFSR has a length of 110 bits according the the BM algorithm for the case that it actually is one LFSR and not two. This is not practical because the application would have to read 110 bits to compute the next bit. We just have a bitrate of 3 kBit/s. The sequence samples' length needs to be around 230 bits for the BM algorithm to find the LFSR.

Comment: @kodlu I added a sample of the sequence. What I basically need is a way to reduce the number of bits that I need to compute the next bit in the sequence.

Comment: Well, the the period is $L_c = L_a \cdot L_b = (2^n - 1)(2^m - 1)$. The proper method is try all possible input values for one LFSR then use BM to see that the sequence is fitting to the other. Do you know the taps and sizes?

Comment: So you mean find the two lengths first and then see if I can come up with two LFSRs of that length, that produces the desired sequence? No, I don't know anything about the taps and sizes. I have to completely reverse-engineer the code.

Comment: @kelalaka Yeah, it doesn't make sense. It would be ``L = (2^110) - 1 = 1.29 e33`` and ``Lc = La * Lb = ((2^50 - 1) * ((2^60) - 1) = 1.29 e33``. I would not be able to reduce the number of bits at all. So this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: How can you write formulas here? Latex didn't work

Comment: It works $a^2$ `$a^2$` Our site has $\LaTeX$\MathJax.

Comment: Think I tried that earlier $L_{c} = L_{a} \cdot L_{b}$. Ah it works! :)

Comment: Well, the period doesn't imply linear-complexity will below. `000001000001000001` is periodic with LC is 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123879/discussion-between-neolith-and-kelalaka).